# timestamp as a document in Firestore, Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know the field can be saved using `@ServertimeStamp`

I want to list the document in `timestamp` order as well.

what is the best way to do this?

Could you please show some code to do this? and explain to me?

> and I want it to be an only number(like 140717313...) not String or
>   something

actually I'm little confused right now there are so many ways to calculate date or time

I need simplest one.. thank you for reading I know this is a silly question but I'm new and confused
I'm sorry

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, did you try something? If so can you share some snippets?

Comment: Why would you like to store the date as a number and not as an Date object?  Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to place a document in time. so you don`t have to write query condition you only need this sentence get ~ \"limit(20)\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To name the document `[serverTimestamp]` do:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
db.collection("collectionName").document(Timestamp.now().seconds.toString()).set()....
```

And to retrieve the values in descending order:

```
val docRef = db.collection("collectionName").orderBy(FieldPath.documentId(), Query.Direction.DESCENDING)).limit(5)
docRef.get()....
```

Comment: sorry I mean I want to name every documents timestamp

Comment: I did this but it named like 
com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue$ServerTimestampFieldValue@4146aca as a document name

Comment: Try now. Timestamp class is from com.google.firebase namespace.

Comment: it has red line. 'second' has private access in 'com.google.firebase.Timestamp'

Comment: I think db.collection("user").document(String.valueOf(Timestamp.now().getSeconds())).set(userMap); this works. is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably compare with Date.getTime(); method it will return you the milliseconds.

Comment: sorry I mean I want to name every documents timestamp